# Can .NET Core 1.1.4 run .NET standard 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-standard

Is it possible to have a .NET core 1.1.4 app run on .NET standard 2 or would .NET core 2.0.9 be required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, .NET Core 1.x only supports libraries targeting `netstandard1.x`.

You'll need to install some version of .NET Core 2 to support libraries targeting `netstandard2.0`.

The [.NET Standard documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) has a table of which platforms support which versions of .NET Standard, and it shows .NET Core 2.0 as the lowest version of .NET Core that supports .NET Standard 2.0.

Comment: The ".NET Implementation support" table in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support might be worth referencing in your answer as it gives the general case as well as the specific one for this question =)

Comment: @Rob: Funnily enough I was just returning to this question to add that very link :)